# How to set default system background color?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a widget, for example a `QComboBox`.

With the function `setStyleSheet("background:red")` I am able to set the background.

But how can I set the color back? I've tried `"background:gray"` and `"background:silver"` but it looks different.

Comment: Cannot you use [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#setBackgroundRole) with QPalette::Window?

Comment: Turn off stylesheets. `setStyleSheet( QString() );`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either completely clear the stylesheet like this:

```
    combobox.setStyleSheet('')
```

or use a [palette-role](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#paletterole), like this:

```
    combobox.setStyleSheet('background: palette(window)')
```